# UI scaling in different screen size using React Native

Tags: react-native

I am very new to programming and I am currently using react native to make android applications. Now I am just testing out my code in my own physical smartphone. I want to know if it is more apt  to use '%' unit in dimensions to properly scale apps in different phone sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon your UI like how your UI is look like, But general approach is use react native default view property like flex, flexbox which have different property as per your UI so it will scale your UI in any point upto 99% of devices. Some of devices may very depend on resolution and screen height so for that you can use % in width and height but remember only specific condition not every where .

General View style you can refer this

https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props

https://reactnative.dev/docs/image-style-props

https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props

https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props

https://reactnative.dev/docs/view-style-props

For simple login screen UI you can refer this example so you can get idea how react native UI we can create generalize

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/common-react-native-app-layouts-login-page--cms-27639